# How to create custom C++ template that receives any type such as STL vector?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create data structure for sorting data that will firstly receive any kind of object, i.e. `int`, `string` or `MyCustomObject` and then perform other tasks.

```cpp
// heap.h
template <typename T>
class Heap{
public:
    Heap();
    ~Heap();    
}


//heap.cpp
template <typename T>
Heap<T>::Heap(){}

template <typename T>
Heap<T>::~Heap(){}

...
```

It turns out that from the very beginning when I try to run `Heap<int> test` it shows that classic message `undefined reference to Heap<int>::Heap()`. I found out that one workaround is to add `template <typename int>` at the end of the code.

However, if I try to do it with `std::vector` I'm pretty sure I can run `std::vector<MyCustomObject> test` which uses templates even without adding that line `template<typename MyCustomObject>` beforehand.

I want to know:

1. How would I perform this same behavior in my data structure of receiving "unknown" types?
2. Why `std::vector` implementation works whereas mine don't? What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `undefined reference to Heap<int>::Heap()` error you have to put the definition into the header file, too. Yes, that may seem strange, but that is [the usual approach with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file):

heap.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
class Heap{
public:
    Heap();
    ~Heap();
};

template <typename T>
Heap<T>::Heap(){}

template <typename T>
Heap<T>::~Heap(){}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "heap.hpp"

int main()
{
  Heap<int> test_with_int;
  Heap<double> test_with_double;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++20 is adding modules. But you need to find a C++20 conforming compiler

Comment: What do you mean by that @BasileStarynkevitch?

Comment: As far as I known. C++20 has yet to see widespread adoption by major compilers. Even the newest GCC and Clang compilers only provide partial support for C++20 so far.

Comment: @testing_22: [this webpage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) explains what C++20 modules are. [this wikipage](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) explains what [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has implemented, you need to use a very recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler in 2021